# Deleting first letter of each line

Tags: bash

I have a file and I need to delete its first letter of each lines. I tried this:

```
for i in
do
if [ $5 -eq cat harfler | grep `head -n i harfler | head -c 1` ]
then
echo "succeded"
tr -d `head -n i`
fi
done
```

but nothing happens. Doesn't even echo "succeeded". Any idea why?

Comment: replace $5 with $1

Comment: use cut instead of head

Comment: Hi sagar, it is actually just a part of my code so that I need to use $5 the problem is not about it. And I need to use head, this is a homework actually. I don't understand why this thing doesn't work.

Comment: @zahedae why you don't use simple way in answers?

Comment: Hi @KasiyA I appriciate the answer you suggest, but this is a homework and I need to do in this way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @zahedae can you tell what do you want to do by above commands exactly? This make the question more understandable for quickly help to you. you can post the sample input and an example of your desired result would be great. thank you

Comment: Hi @KasiyA thanks for your help. What I'm trying to do is to write a script that works like: **readData -f filedirectory -n filename -c character** And I want to delete filename's lines start with character. Also there is two options in this homework. I can delete the lines start with character or I can echo the lines start with character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed as following:

```
sed 's/^.//' file
```

For line if starts with spaces:

```
sed 's/\S//' file
```

Matches any non-white space character but not newline. You can use `\w` or `[A-Za-z0-9_]` instead.

The command suggested by @gleenjackman:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]//' file
```

or

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]]//' file
```

or

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]//' file
```

or contains numbers:

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]//' file
```

or use:

```
while read line; do echo "${line:1}" ;done < file
```

Comment: Probably requires GNU sed for `\S` and `\w`. Portably, you'd write `[^[:blank:]]`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, you are right and thanks, added that too.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using

**sed -**

```
sed 's/^.\{1\}//g' <filename>
```

**cut -**

```
cut -c 2- <filename>
```